# compiler is out of heap space in pass 2 - anonymous union, anonymous structs, constexpr constructor, static member

Tags: c++, static, unions, constexpr, anonymous-struct

I have code that fails to compile with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with the following error:

> fatal error C1002: compiler is out of heap space in pass 2

### The Code

```
struct Int { int i; };

struct B {
    union {
        struct { int x; };
        struct { Int y; };
    };

    constexpr B() : x(1) {}
};

struct A { static B b; };

B A::b;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

This is the simplest I've been able to boil down the fail state through trial and error, but there's still quite a bit going on.

What has me dumbfounded is that each of the following changes cause it to compile just fine...

Removing `constexpr` from `B`'s constructor makes it work:

```
struct Int { int i; };

struct B {
    union {
        struct { int x; };
        struct { Int y; };
    };

    B() : x(1) {} // <---<<    ( constexpr B() : x(1) {} )
};

struct A { static B b; };

B A::b;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Changing `A`'s variable to be not `static` makes it work:

```
struct Int { int i; };

struct B {
    union {
        struct { int x; };
        struct { Int y; };
    };

    constexpr B() : x(1) {}
};

struct A { B b; }; // <---<<    ( struct A { static B b; }; B A::b; )

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Using a plain `int` in `B`'s `union`'s second `struct` instead of an `int` wrapper makes it work:

```
struct Int { int i; };

struct B {
    union {
        struct { int x; };
        struct { int y; }; // <---<<    ( struct { Int y; }; )
    };

    constexpr B() : x(1) {}
};

struct A { static B b; };

B A::b;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Default-initializing `x` in `B`'s constructor rather than passing `1` makes it work:

```
struct Int { int i; };

struct B {
    union {
        struct { int x; };
        struct { Int y; };
    };

    constexpr B() : x() {} // <---<<    ( constexpr B() : x(1) {} )
};

struct A { static B b; };

B A::b;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, taking `B`'s `union`'s `Int` member out of structs makes it work:

```
struct Int { int i; };

struct B {
    union {
        struct { int x; };
        Int y; // <---<<    ( struct { Int y; }; )
    };

    constexpr B() : x(1) {}
};

struct A { static B b; };

B A::b;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Suffice to say, I'm at a complete loss. I would greatly appreciate any assistance from someone who understands the compiler better than I do.

Comment: There's nothing to understand. You found a compiler bug. Congratulations. File a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: That's just MSVC being stupid. Works on gcc and clang. File a bug report if you have the time and motivation, you have the MCVE down already it seems. (Good job on that btw!)

Comment: note: Anonymous structs are not permitted in Standard C++